# Выполнение нескольких запросов в одном PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Есть некое множество, на основе которого требуется сделать N запросов. Я хочу объединить их в один запрос и выполнить. Как сделать это правильно?

```
private static final String DELETE_PERMISSION_QUERY = "DELETE FROM `" + TABLE + "` WHERE permission = ? AND server = ?;";

public void deleteExpiredPermissions(Set<Permission> expiredPermissions) {

    for (Permission permission : expiredPermissions) {
        this.connection = getConnection();
        try (PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(DELETE_PERMISSION_QUERY)) {
            ps.setString(1, permission.getPermission());
            ps.setString(2, this.server);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            flushLastExecute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            this.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not delete permission: " + permission.getPermission(), ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connection = getConnection();
try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(DELETE_PERMISSION_QUERY)) {
    for (Permission permission : expiredPermissions) {
        ps.setString(1, permission.getPermission());
        ps.setString(2, this.server);
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException exc) {
    this.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not delete permission", exc);
}
```